# C# async/await strange behavior in console app

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I built some async/await demo console app and get strange result. Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void BeginLongIO(Action act)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In BeginLongIO start... {0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        act();
        Console.WriteLine("In BeginLongIO end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public static Int32 EndLongIO()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In EndLongIO start... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("In EndLongIO end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return 42;
    }

    public static Task<Int32> LongIOAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync start... {0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Int32>();
        BeginLongIO(() =>
        {
            try { tcs.TrySetResult(EndLongIO()); }
            catch (Exception exc) { tcs.TrySetException(exc); }
        });
        Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public async static Task<Int32> DoAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In DoAsync start... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var res = await LongIOAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("In DoAsync end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return res;
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine("In Main start... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        DoAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("In Main exec... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("In Main end... \t\t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    private static Int64 ticks;
}
```

The result bellow:

[image]

Maybe I do not fully understand what exactly makes await. I thought if the execution comes to await then the execution returns to the caller method and task for awaiting runs in another thread. In my example all operations execute in one thread and the execution doesn't returns to the caller method after await keyword.
Where is the truth?

Comment: you may watch this : https: //channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Mads-Torgersen-Inside-C-Async

Comment: `I thought if the execution comes to await then the execution returns to the caller method and task for awaiting runs in another thread.` Every single `async` intro I'm aware of (including [mine](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)) goes out of its way to explicitly state this *isn't* what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how `async-await` works.

Marking a method as `async` doesn't create any background threads. When you call an `async` method it runs synchronously until an asynchronous point and only then returns to the caller.

That asynchronous point is when you `await` a task that haven't completed yet. When it does complete the rest of the method is scheduled to be executed. This task should represent an actual asynchronous operation (like I/O, or `Task.Delay`).

In your code there is no asynchronous point, there's no point in which the calling thread is returned. The thread just goes deeper and deeper and blocks on `Thread.Sleep` until these methods are completed and `DoAsync` returns.

Take this simple example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    // calling thread
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // different ThreadPool thread
}
```

Here we have an actual asynchronous point (`Task.Delay`) the calling thread returns to `Main` and then blocks synchronously on the task. After a second the `Task.Delay` task is completed and the rest of the method is executed on a different `ThreadPool` thread.

If instead of `Task.Delay` we would have used `Thread.Sleep` then it will all run on the same calling thread.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's helpfull. 
Then my next question: how works await for the task that returns from the task-based wrapper for methods that follow to the APM pattern like BeginReceive and EndReceive from Socket class? This wrapper uses TaskCompletionSource and returns completed task too. Where are there an asynchronous point?

Comment: @Jeksonic The TCS usage is fine. The thing is the Begin/End methods in .Net are already asynchronous. So when you call `Begin` it just starts an operation and releases a thread. Only when the operation completes it will call the provided callback.

Comment: @Jeksonic In your case. The `Begin` method just blocks the calling thread, and then calls the callback so the thread isn't released.

Comment: Please don't call `Task.Wait` on async code. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Gusdor You're in `Main`. In an example. It's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I filled some gaps in my understanding of async-await.

Comment: @Jeksonic sure.. any time.

Comment: @i3arnon how does the asker know when it isn't fine?

Comment: @Gusdor I don't know. Do you want to ask them?

Answer (score 1):

To really understand this behaviour, you need to first understand what `Task` is and what `async` and `await` actually do to your code.

`Task` is the CLR representation of "an activity". It could be a method executing on a worker-pool thread. It could be an operation to retrieve some data from a database over a network. Its generic nature allows it to encapsulate many different implementations, but fundamentally you need to understand that it just means "an activity".

The `Task` class gives you ways to examine the state of the activity: whether it has completed, whether it has yet to start, whether it generated an error, etc. This modelling of an activity allows us to more easily compose programs which are built as a sequence of activities, rather than a sequence of method calls.

Consider this trivial code:

```
public void FooBar()
{
    Foo();
    Bar();
}
```

What this means is "execute method `Foo`, then execute method `Bar`. If we consider an implementation that returns `Task` from `Foo` and `Bar`, the composition of these calls is different:

```
public void FooBar()
{
    Foo().Wait();
    Bar().Wait();
}
```

The meaning is now "Start a task using the method `Foo` and wait for it to finish, then start a task using the method `Bar` and wait for it to finish." Calling `Wait()` on a `Task` is rarely correct - it causes the current thread to block until the `Task` completes and can cause deadlocks under some commonly-used threading models - so instead we can use `async` and `await` to achieve a similar effect without this dangerous call.

```
public async Task FooBar()
{
    await Foo();
    await Bar();
}
```

The `async` keyword causes execution of your method to be broken down into chunks: each time you write `await`, it takes the following code and generates a "continuation": a method to be executed as a `Task` after the awaited task completes.

This is different from `Wait()`, because a `Task` is not linked to any particular execution model. If the `Task` returned from `Foo()` represents a call over the network, there is no thread blocked, waiting for the result - there is a `Task` waiting for the operation to complete. When the operation completes, the `Task` is scheduled for execution - this scheduling process allows a separation between the definition of the activity and the method by which it is executed, and is the power in the use of tasks.

So, the method can be summarised as:

- start the task `Foo()`
- when that task completes start the task `Bar`
- when that task completes indicate the method task has completed

---

In your console app, you aren't awaiting any `Task` that represents the pending IO operation, which is why you see a blocked thread - there is never an opportunity to set up a continuation which would execute asynchronously.

We can fix your LongIOAsync method to simulate your long IO in an asynchronous fashion by using the `Task.Delay()` method. This method returns a `Task` that completes after a specified period. This gives us the opportunity for an asynchronous continuation.

```
public static async Task<Int32> LongIOAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync start... {0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    await Task.Delay(1000);       

    Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the line that actually runs something on a background thread is

```
   Task.Run( () => {  } );
```

In your example you are not awaiting that Task but that of a TaskCompletionSource

```
   public static Task<int> LongIOAsync()
   {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Int32>();

        Task.Run ( () => BeginLongIO(() =>
        {
            try { tcs.TrySetResult(EndLongIO()); }
            catch (Exception exc) { tcs.TrySetException(exc); }
        }));

        return tcs.Task;    
   }
```

When awaiting LongIOAsync you are awaiting the the task from tcs witch is set from a background thread in a delegate given to Task.Run()

apply this change :

```
    public static Task<Int32> LongIOAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync start... {0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Int32>();

        Task.Run ( () => BeginLongIO(() =>
        {
            try { tcs.TrySetResult(EndLongIO()); }
            catch (Exception exc) { tcs.TrySetException(exc); }
        }));

        Console.WriteLine("In LongIOAsync end... \t{0} {1}", (DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Alternately in this case you could of just awaited the returned from Task.Run() , 
TaskCompletionSource is for situations where you want to pass around the ability to set your Task as complete or other wise.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that LongIOAsync() is blocking. If you run this in a GUI program you will actually see the GUI freezes briefly - not the way async/await is supposed to work. Therefore the entire thing falls apart.

You need to wrap all the long running operations in a *Task* then directly await on that Task. Nothing should block during that.